# Firebase Push Notifications with Objective C not working in ios 11.4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implement Firebase Push Messaging service. I got Push in iOS 9.0, 10.0, 11.0  but not getting a push in iOS 11.4.1. Would you please help me to resolve this issue.

```
[FIRApp configure];
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setDelegate:self];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
     requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     }
     ];

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
#endif
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```